# Compositing Render layers node two scenes two resolutions

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes, multiresolution

The context :
I have two scenes let's call them S1 and S2. 
S1 has a camera of a resolution of 1080*1080 (square).
S2 has a camera of a resolution of 1080*1920 (vertical).
I have created a composition in S1 that looks like this :

[image: Composition]

I get a rendered image that is a square whereas the render layer should be vertical. I wanted to have a vertical image inside a square canvas. I know i could have used a image node or movie node directly into S1 composition. I just want to be able to compose multiple render layers with different resolution into a square canvas. How could it be achieved?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts. I suggest editing your question down to just one question (by using the [edit] link below it) and asking the other one separately. Thanks

Comment: Hi Ray, i added the second question because it is related to the first. I ll edit and put the second question into a new post i guess the probability to get an answer could be higher.